# How to batch rewrite history in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I would like to batch-edit a number of commits to automatically make modifications to author and commit message (being able to apply a few regular expressions would be fine).

I am aware that this is rewriting history, will cause trouble if there are clones, and will change commit ids.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Are author's names in these commits are unique or exist somewhere in history also?

Comment: @LazyBadger Either can be arranged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hg export -g -o <outfile>`, process `outfile` with whatever tool you like, and re-import with `hg import <outfile>`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Most easily automated way: [MQ](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension)

In short:

- qimport -r REV
- qrefresh (`-u` for user, `-m`|`-l` for commit message)
- qfinish+qdelete

with (probably) restoring the correct order of changesets (can't recall where qfinished cset will appear in DAG)

2. Two-steps (with tricks and limitations) way

   - Rewrite authors with [Convert Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) (Mercurial->Mercurial conversion) with [`--authormap`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--authors_.2F_--authormap) (unique authors are needed)
   - Change commit-messages with [histedit](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension)